# How to add element as column stack in html container?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want default html structure like this :

[image]

i need to add dyanimcally Add rectangebox and it must be turn out like this

[image]

How could i do this ?

what i did is something like this :

```
<div style="width:400px;">
        <ul id="UlPopUp" style="-webkit-columns: 2; -moz-columns: 2; columns: 2;">
            <li id='liLeftDescriptions'>
                <span>Item1
                </span>
            </li>
            <li id='liLeftSkills'>
                <span>Item1</span>
            </li>
            <li id='liLeftClient'>
                <span>Item1</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6eq56/

Comment: We need more information. What have you tried? What's worked and what hasn't? All you've given us so far is "I want to do this!"

Comment: Thanks for reply , i already tired to set css like this :style="-webkit-columns: 2; -moz-columns: 2; columns: 2;" in UL , but did not work, cause i need 4 items in 1 column, when 5 item come it should be go in coumns 2

Answer (score 1):

I think you might use something like that :

```
var div_to_append = "<li class='some_class'><span>Item1</span></li>"
$("#clickBtn").on("click", function() {
$("#UlPopUp").append(div_to_append);
});
```

I used a `button` check out the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6eq56/2/

I supposed that you want to fire the event `on click` or something similar

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var elem = $("<div class='item'></div>");
    if($('.col1>div').length < 4)
        $('.col1').append(elem);
    else
        $('.col2').append(elem);
});
```